# Loop for few .prop actions Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make infinite loop out of few actions of marking `<input>` radio buttons checked one after another delayed by a second. I also want to be able to break it by .click event then. So far i managed to write down this piece of code but it immedietaly goes to last action. Also when i try using while(true) loop my browser crashes.

```
<input type="radio" name="nav" id="first"/>
<input type="radio" name="nav" id="second"/>
<input type="radio" name="nav" id="third"/>



$(document).ready(function (){
    setTimeout(function(){$("#third").prop('checked',true); }, 1000);     
    setTimeout(function(){$("#second").prop('checked',true); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#first").prop('checked',true); }, 1000);    
});
```

I am new to JQuery and js

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have infinite elements or infinite amount of times you want to make the checkbox set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust or use the callback:

**Adjust**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#third").prop('checked',true); }, 1000);     
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#second").prop('checked',true); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#first").prop('checked',true); }, 3000);    
});
```

**Call Back**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#third").prop('checked', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#second").prop('checked', true);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#first").prop('checked', true);
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Applying the same logic for your infinite one, **this is your solution**:

```
$(function () {
  $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.prop("checked", true);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

**Breaking by click event:**

So have another `<input type="button" />` element:

```
<input type="button" id="break" value="Break" />
```

And attach this event handler:

```
$("#break").click(function () {
  clearInterval(checker);
});
```

For this to work, you need to modify the above code a bit.

```
$(function () {
  breaker = setInterval(function () {
    if ($("input:checked").next("input:checkbox:not(:checked)"))
      clearInterval(breaker);
    $("input:checked").next("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Update:** This is more scalable and workable.

Comment: Well, people can explain the downvote, so that I can guide better.

Comment: Thanks and how to make infinite loop out of this? Not really my downvote. Unless I don't know about sth at stackexchange ;)

Comment: @KulZAus Updated the answer. Kindly check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: My screen was only scrolled far enough to see the very first part of your answer and I was half ready to down vote when I scrolled to read the rest. `setInterval` is the appropriate method for this case. +1

Comment: @JoelEtherton Thanks. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

Using `while(true)` to accomplish this is certainly going to cause problems. Basically anything that uses `while(true)` without a `break` statement is going to lock the UI.

However, it is certainly possible to make an infinite loop out of these. There are several way to prepare the selection here. They can all be selected by their name ("nav") for example, or by id, or that they are all inputs, or that they perhaps sit beneath another element. For simplicity, I will just seed with their ids, but it is possible to gather them in several other ways as listed previously.

```js
//arrange the selectors
var ids = ["first","second","third"];

//setup the state of the loop
var current = 0, timer = -1, on = false;

//loop mechanic
function loopSelect(){
 timer = setTimeout(function(){
     current %= ids.length;
     $("#"+ids[(current++)%ids.length]).prop("checked",true);
     if(on)loopSelect();
 },1000);
}

//attach event handler
$("#b").click(function(){
    if(on){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        on = false;
        $('.on').hide();
        $('.off').show();
    }else{
        on = true;
        loopSelect();
        $('.on').show();
        $('.off').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.on{
  display:none;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
}
.off{
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}

.indicators span{
  padding:6px;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="b">Click to cycle the infinite loop</button>
</div>

<p class="indicators">
  <span class="on">on</span>
  <span class="off">off</span>
</p>

<p>
 <input type="radio" name="nav" id="first"/>
 <input type="radio" name="nav" id="second"/>
 <input type="radio" name="nav" id="third"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but may be helpful for people coming back later. If you're using ES6/ES2015 or later, you can use an 
iterator, assuming you have an unlimited number of elements that you want to cycle through.

Note: this code doesn't rely on ES6, but this example uses the [`iterator` protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

```js
function makeIterator(elems){
    var nextIndex = 0;
    
    return {
       next: function() {
           elems.eq(nextIndex).prop('checked', 'checked');
           return nextIndex < elems.length ?
               {value: elems.eq(nextIndex++), done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    }
}

$(function() {
    var doCheck = makeIterator($('input[type=radio]'));
    var runIterator = setInterval(function() {
        if (doCheck.next().done) {
          clearInterval(runIterator);
        }
    }, 1000);
  
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        clearInterval(runIterator);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">
<input type="radio" name="group">

<button id="stop">Stop!</button>
```

Comment: thx random downvoter for downvoting a working, scalable solution